# Push Notification in ios with asp.net

Tags: ios, asp.net, notifications, push

I need to apply push notification in ios mobile apps with asp.net. Have anyone solution in window Microsoft Server ?

Answer (score 1):

Please find Link :
[Push Notification with C#](http://rajendradhanora.blogspot.in/2011/07/iphone-push-notification-using-netc.html)

Make Sure Import certificate from keychain without private key if any excecption occurs

Answer (score 0):

There is step by step process, hope it helps:- 
Below is the link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/pandeypradip/apple-push-notification-using-asp-net/